# ¿Como puedo leer los datos de un db sql en un input text html5?

Tags: php, mysql

Aqui tengo el codigo que funciona con los select...pero no consigo a collegarlo a los input text.

```
 <div class="form-group">
   <input type="text" value="" name="nombrecliente" id="nombrecliente" 
      class="form-control input-lg" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Nombre Cliente"/>
      <?php //*--conexion*//
       $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', '*********', '*****', '********');
       mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, "utf8"); //*--conexion*//                    
       $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM clientesguaca"); //*--variable 
       llamadatos*//
       while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
      echo '<input value="' . $valores[nombrecliente] . '">' . 
      $valores[nombrecliente] . '</>';
      }
      ?>
   </div>
```

Comment: ¿qué es collegarlo? no me queda muy clara tu pregunta!

Answer (score 0):

Intenta de esta manera:

```
<?php 
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', '*********', '*****', '********');
    mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, "utf8");
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM clientesguaca");

?>
  <div class="form-group">
    <?php 
        while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)):?>
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $valores['nombrecliente']; ?>" class="form-control input-lg" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Nombre Cliente">
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    ?>        
   </div>
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta. Tu codigo funciona muy bien!!! Ahora necesito que sea como un autocomplete donde muestra el listado que hay en el db así que comienzas a escribir...

Comment: Si la respuesta fue satisfactoria, marcala como aceptada por favor. Para el tema del autocomplete, te sugiero que abras una nueva pregunta ya que aborda un tema diferente.